# How To Insert Incrementing Numbers with words by Multicursor in jetbrains IDE(IntelliJ IDEA)?

Tags: intellij-idea, live-templates

I want to add Incrementing Numbers with words by Multicursor in jetbrains IDE(IntelliJ IDEA) .

Is there any way to do it by Live template? I want to do things like this image :

[image]

Comment: There is no such feature in IntelliJ IDEA out of the box that could do something like that.

Comment: @yole How about making that an answer? Even if "not possible" is probably not the answer the OP hoped for ;-) (BTW I would find that feature useful myself, every now and then.)

Comment: Not possible out of the box != not possible.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

You could use [String Manipulation plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/2162?pr=idea) to do that (`Increment/Decrement | Increment duplicates` or `Create sequence`).

[image]

Comment: Tried it ... But  (7.2.182.000.3 June18, 2019) does not work in Clion 2019.2 ![Failing ScreenshotL](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1aY8zZlXIWj0_SSCSbINhsrSFp84DnwlG).

Comment: Thanks! For me, on latest IntelliJ it is Highlight with shift + home, right click, "string manipulation", "Create sequence".

Answer (score 11):

The plugin is not working on my WebStorm, there could be another way using unix command line:

`seq 1 10 | xargs printf 'string%d\n'`

Comment: String Manipulation plugin? Then report a bug.

Comment: good for being faster for the 1-time case, plus it's useful when using another ide.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually do that without plugins.

1. select a list of numbers with your preferred method
2. copy
3. select target positions
4. paste

I select the original numbers by:

- selecting the rate word
- ctrl+G (for multi line selection)
- place the cursor right before the `e` and the first number (just press right arrow)
- shift+option+ > (right arrow). That moves to the end of the word while selecting

other option is multicursor with shift+option+cmd+paint selection (macos)

Same in the target.

[image: demo]

Comment: That's just copypasting.

Comment: And it would only go so far as you copied.
Meaning can't automatically work despite number of selections.